# Use cmake to create a cmake-free Makefile

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, makefile, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm using cmake to try and build a project on Linux.
It generates a Unix Makefile system, which is very nice.
The problem is that I can't build on another machine with this Makefile if cmake is not install on that machine.
Is there any option or flag I can set on cmake so that it generates a Makefile that doesn't call cmake in it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not possible. CMake uses itself inside the Makefiles for dependency scanning and updating the Makefiles, if a CMakelists.txt file has changed. This cannot work, if cmake is not available during the build.

Comment: Also, CMake is locating various libraries and include directories, so generated Makefiles have them hardcoded. If you try to use these paths on another machine there may be errors.